# Input datepicker error changes date format on change with polish culture

Tags: html, jquery, input, datepicker, asp.net-core-mvc

My problem is when i change the datepicker in polish culture. First of all is correct the datepicker format is correct like 01.01.2021.

[image: Correct format]

But when i change to another date selecter from datepicker:

[image: Polish datepicker]

The input format has changed.

[image: Incorrect format]

Is there anyway to solve this? I'm using mvc net core and this sentence to create datepicker:

In the model the property is set as Datetime with         [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
.

Thank you.

Comment: `$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["pl"]);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but its not working for me setDefaults is undefined.

Comment: Hi @Arturo,did you use bootstrap datepicker?There are several datepicker libraries,please share which one you use.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap datepicker, maybe the reason can be that datepicker not allow "." separators?